# Keyframed element getting on top of fixed div when scrolling

Tags: html, css

So, I have a **bouncing arrow** using pure css, and it is roughfully in the middle of the page. I also have a **div** on the top which is fixed. When I scroll the page, the elements go under that title div, as intended. But when the bouncing arrow reachs the title div, it is not going under it, it goes on top of that div.

**Body CSS:**

```
body {
    background: url("images/1080-620.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Title div CSS:**

```
#title{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 162, 146);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 6% 0 4% 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:500;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(146, 77, 42, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
}
```

**Bouncing arrow CSS:**

```
.arrow{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 6% auto 6% auto;
    background-image: url("huge-base-64");
    background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
```

**Bouncing arrow in the middle of the page:**

[image]

**Elements going under the title div as intended:**

[image]

**When the Arrow reachs the title div:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding z-indexing to your elements?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Check ```z-index``` as suggested by @DylanAnlezark, you can also shorthand write your css as follow: ```div {background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300) center/cover fixed;```

Comment: @DylanAnlezark @ battaboombattabaam, yes, thank you guys, the z-index thing fixed it, I'll try to learn more about it, <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coming up against stacking contexts.

The title div starts a new stacking context (because of its position fixed) but so also does the bouncing arrow (because of its transforms).

See: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context` which gives a list of the (quite extensive) situations in which a new stacking context is formed. You may need to check the other content in your site to ensure other elements don't go above the title - so choosing a practical, i.e. large enough, z-index for the fixed div.

In this snippet the title div is given a z-index of 1. The bouncing arrow isn't specifically given a z-index so it'll have the default and go under the fixed div.

```css
body {
    background: url("images/1080-620.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

#title{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(255, 162, 146);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 6% 0 4% 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:500;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(146, 77, 42, 0.2);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.arrow{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 6% auto 6% auto;
    background-image: url("huge-base-64");
    background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

.filler {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, cyan, blue);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">TITLE - try scrolling the blue div</div>
<div class="filler"></div>
<div class="arrow bounce" style="background-color: magenta;"></div>
<div class="filler"></div>
```

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thank you Haworth, the z-index did the trick!